# CloudBlobContainer.BreakLeaseAsync vs ReleaseLeaseAsync

Tags: azure

What is the difference between these two methods?

CloudBlobContainer.BreakLeaseAsync Method

- Initiates an asynchronous operation that breaks the lease on this container.

CloudBlobContainer.ReleaseLeaseAsync Method

- Initiates an asynchronous operation that releases the lease on this container.

What is the difference between breaking and releasing the lease?

I've included the descriptions from this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer?view=azure-dotnet-legacy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create (acquire) a lease, you can specify how long a client can hold the lease which can be between 15 and 60 seconds or infinity (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-blob)).

If the client **breaks** the lease, the current lease lock timer still continues counting until it reaches 0, then other clients can acquire the lease.

If the client **releases** the lease, other clients can immediately acquire a lease, no matter what the duration counter shows.

Comment: What happens when you break an infinite lease?

Comment: My guess is that if you break a lease with unlimited duration, it'd be stuck in breaking status except you supply a `x-ms-lease-break-period` as part of the request to break the lease. see the [lease state statuses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-blob?tabs=microsoft-entra-id#lease-states)